# meaning of "image-searching is strictly for those who want to get sacked"

Tags: reading-comprehension

I’m reading The Greedy Queen by Annie Gray. In the introduction, she introduces Queen Victoria as:

> Myths about Queen Victoria are plentiful, and largely unproven or
>   taken out of context, from the ‘not amused’ comment, to the
>   accusations that she slept with or even married John Brown, and
>   **image-searching Prince Albert at work is strictly for those who want
>   to get sacked.**

I’ve nearly finished reading this book. But I still can’t figure out what the part in bold means. Considering the book is about Victorian Age, “image-searching” seems to be a very modern term and I don’t understand what it means in this sentence. “Image-searching is strictly for those who want to get sacked” seems to be implying something in a very indirect way. In the later chapters, the author mentions that Queen Victoria was so soft-hearted that she would not sack her servants. This doesn't seem to explain the sentence in question. I can’t find any relevant anecdotes on the internet, either. Can anybody help me understand what this sentence is saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it makes you feel better, I had no idea what a "Prince Albert" is, so the sentence meant little to me as well.

This is less about knowing English as it is about knowing the subject matter.  Basically, the sentence has a double meaning.  It turns out that ["Prince Albert"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert,_Prince_Consort) was the husband and consort of Queen Victoria.  Presumably they enjoyed sex together, since they had quite a few children before his untimely death.

It's *also* the [name for a kind of *intimate* piercing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Albert_(genital_piercing)) (image NSFW).  If you look at images of this piercing while at work, you will probably get in trouble.  "To get sacked" is (mostly British, although some Americans use it) slang that means "to be fired from your job".

Fortunately, if you actually google "Prince Albert", the vast majority of the images are safe for work (unless you specify the *other* kind).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning as a footnote that "get sacked" is an informal way to say "be fired from your job."

Answer (score 2):

It is a note to the reader, rather than a comment about Victorian England. A “Prince Albert” in modern slang has sexual connotations. I should put a reference, but maybe I can use the excuse that I am at work and don’t want to search for a suitable link...

Oh, ok then: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Albert_(genital_piercing) (not suitable for work)